# Azure AD B2C built-in attributes using custom policies?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-create-custom-attributes-profile-edit-custom) for adding extension attributes to a custom policy states:

> Your Azure AD B2C directory comes with a built-in set of attributes.
>   Examples are Given Name, Surname, City, Postal Code, and
>   userPrincipalName.

I am using the starter pack specified in the same documentation and it contains what looks like a custom attribute for "surName". Surname however is listed as an example of a built-in attribute.

Is "surName" a built-in attribute?

Where can I find documentation on all the built-in attributes and how to reference them in my policy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"surname" is a built-in attribute.

I don't believe there is a documented list of the built-in attributes but here is a known list of them:

- objectId
- accountEnabled
- city
- country
- displayName
- givenName
- jobTitle
- otherMails
- postalCode
- signInNames
- signInNames.emailAddress
- signInNames.userName
- state
- streetAddress
- surname
- userIdentities

Basically, if it is [a declared property of the user entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity), then you can declare a claim type for it.

Comment: How does it get linked to the built-in attribute? Is it simply a matter of having the claim type id matching the claim name?